# BeautifulSoup4 not findall() not getting all of the links on the webpage

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab all of the 'a' links from a webpage:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source_code = requests.get(starting_url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    print(href)
```

and the list printed out it not all links on the page. if I try and print out plain_text, I can sea all these links, but they are not printed as href.

First week learning python! All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

Update: I forgot to share the plaint_text file here. Sorry for the confusion.

The plain_text is pretty long so I'll just post the starting_url

```
starting_url = 'https://freeexampapers.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=101&jsmallfib=1&dir=JSROOT/IB'
```

and yes I'm a high school student:-)

Comment: can you share url

Comment: If you don't wish to give us the url then could you should us a section of `plain_text` that contains an `a` element with an href attribute that isn't printed?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any data sample we can give you sample that 
you could try :-

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,"html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    print link.get('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import fileinput

Link = 'https://animetosho.org/view/jacobswaggedup-kill-la-kill-bd-1280x720-mp4-batch.n677876'
q = requests.get(Link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)
#print soup
subtitles = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'links'})
#print subtitles


with  open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:
    for link in subtitles:
        x = link.find_all('a', limit=26)
        for a in x:
            url = a['href']
            f.write(url+'\n')
```

Now, if you want to do something like store the links in a text file, do the following.

```
# Store the links we need in a list
links_to_keep = []
with open("Anilinks.txt", "r") as f:

     for line in f.readlines():
         if 'solidfiles.com' in line:
             links_to_keep.append(line)

# Write all the links in our list to the file
with open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:

    for link in links_to_keep:
        f.write(link)
```